# Perl: passing hash by ref using rule1

Tags: perl, hash

I am still unclear about why by ref portion is showing undefined value for `%Q` and `$_` uninitialized. I have been looking through [`perlreftut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) and still unable to see what I have done wrong. Passing the hash as a flat array has no issue.

Doing it by ref with `testRef(\%mkPara)` passes a scalar hash reference to the subroutine, right? So, does `my %Q = %{$_}` not turn it back into a hash?

```
use strict;
use diagnostics;
use warnings;

my %mkPara = ('aa'=>2,'bb'=>3,'cc'=>4,'dd'=>5);

sub testFlat
{
    my %P = @_;
    print "$P{'aa'}, $P{'bb'}, ", $P{'cc'}*$P{'dd'}, "\n";  
}

sub testRef
{
    my %Q = %{$_}; #can't use an undefined value as HASH reference
    #print  $_->{'aa'}, "\n";#Use of uninitialized value
    print $Q{'aa'},"\n";
}

#testFlat(%mkPara);
testRef(\%mkPara);
```

Comment: What's "rule1"? And you are passing *a ref to a hash*, not passing *a hash by ref* (which means something quite different, and not possible to do in Perl unless you fudge it using prototypes).

Comment: It's because `@_` and `$_` are completely different variables. I'll just reiterate my suggestion to find yourself a good book or well-structured tutorial. Poking at this at random clearly isn't working well for you.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

When you use arguments in a function call (`\%mkPara` in your case), you can access them through `@_` array inside the function.

Here, you pass a single argument to the function : `\%mkPara`, which you can then access by accessing the first element of `@_` by using `$_[0]`.

`$_` is the default variable for some builtin functions/operators (`print`, `m//`, `s///`, `chomp` and a lot more). Usually seen in `while` or `for` loops. But in your code, you have no reason to use it (you are never setting it to anything, so it's still set to `undef`, hence the error `"Can't use an undefined value as a HASH reference"`.

So your function should actually be :

```
sub testRef
{
    my %Q = %{$_[0]}; # instead of %{$_}
    print  $_[0]->{'aa'}, "\n"; # instead of $_->{'aa'}
    print $Q{'aa'},"\n";
}
```

If needed, you can find more about functions on [perlsub](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlsub.html).

**However**, as @Ikegami pointed out in the comments, using `my %Q = %{$_[0]};` creates a copy of the hash you sent to the function, which in most cases (including that one where you just print a key of the hash) is very suboptimal as you could just use a hashref (like you are doing when you do `$_[0]->{'aa'}`).
You can use hash references like this (roughly the same example as the answer of @Zaid) :

```
sub testRef
{
    my ( $Q ) = @_;
    print $Q->{aa} ;
    print $_, "\n" for keys %$Q;
}
testRef(\%mkPara);
```

There are quite a lot of resources about references online, for instance [`perlreftut`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html) that you were already looking at.

Comment: Thank you @Dada. Now it is clear; didn't even come close to thinking about asking for an element inside but it makes sense now. Appreciate the pointer to perlsub too.

Comment: @ikegami indeed, I added a paragraph to suggest the use of references instead. Thanks for pointing it out.

Answer (score 6):

This can seem a bit tricky at first, but the reason is that `$_` is not the same as `@_`.

From [`perlvar`](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlvar.html):

- `$_` is the implicit/"default" variable that does not have to be spelled out explicitly for certain functions (e.g. [`split`](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/split.html) )
- Within a subroutine the array `@_` contains the parameters passed to that subroutine

---

So the reason why

```
my %Q = %{$_};
```

says you can't use an undefined value as hash reference is because `$_` is not defined.

What you really need here is

```
my %Q = %{$_[0]};
```

because that is the first element of `@_`, which is what was passed to `testRef` in the first place.

---

In practice I tend to find myself doing things a little differently because it lends itself to flexibility for future modifications:

```
sub testRef {

    my ( $Q ) = @_;
    print $_, "\n" for keys %$Q;  # just as an example
}
```

Comment: Many thanks @Zaid. Stipulating an element part completely stumped me. Need to have a play with your flexible version to understand the use of parentheses around $Q.

Comment: They're used to force a list assignent. Without the parens, `@_` would be evaluated in scalar context (returning the number of elements in it) rather than in list context (returning the elements in it).